# create a index from pdf

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Index PDF files and search for keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822884/how-do-i-index-pdf-files-and-search-for-keywords)

Create an index out of a PDF.

Comment: What have you got so far?. If using Python, look into the `collections` module.

Comment: Oh look.  Many, many people have asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+index+pdf.  You too, can use the "Search" box on the top of the page and see what others have asked that might help you.

Comment: "Which is not close to what I'm looking for".  Not helpful at all.  Please carefully and fully define how your requirements actually are different.  We have no idea what's unique or different about what you're doing.  It appears identical to us.

Comment: @S.Lott - different to index pages in one file compared to between documents, as the pagination in the source document is critical

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) Python library for this.
This code show numbers of pages which include required word:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

input = PdfFileReader(file("YourPDFFile.pdf", "rb"))

numberOfPages = input.getNumPages()

i = 1
while i <  numberOfPages:
    oPage = input.getPage(i)
    text = oPage.extractText()
    text.encode('utf8', 'ignore')
    if text.find('What are you looking for') != -1:
        print i
    i += 1
```

The same but working with Python 3

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

input = PdfFileReader(open("YourPDFFile.pdf", "rb"))

numberOfPages = input.getNumPages()

i = 1
while i <  numberOfPages:
    oPage = input.getPage(i)
    text = oPage.extractText()
    text.encode('utf8', 'ignore')
    if text.find('What are you looking for') != -1:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: I think the main problem was that I used Python 2.7 in this script and construction `print` differs in different Python versions [http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html](http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html)

Comment: Just as a note, it'd be a bit more straight forward to make it a for loop, `for i in range(1, numberOfPages):` and to just test `if 'word' in text`

Comment: I haven't used PyPdf but looking through the documentation, it doesn't look like you can. I don't know much about the PDF standard but it's possible that the document itself is defined in terms of pages.

Comment: Glancing through the Wikipedia entry for the PDF standard, it looks like PDF documents are, indeed, defined in terms of page streams. So, you probably do have to interact with the document on a page-by-page basis. You can, of course, build up a large str object containing the extracted text of all the pages and then work with that.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954614/create-an-index-of-the-most-common-words-in-a-pdf-python/6955228#6955228) to your other question sums it up best. Just be sure that your counter is declared outside of your loop, otherwise it will reset with each page (which is what seems to be happening).